# svn status - непонятные файлы

Tags: svn

Вот результат (часть) вывода команды:

```
?       .idea
X       external/devexpress
Performing status on external item at 'external/ibm_websphere':
```

Репозиторий был только склонирован, ничего не добавлялось/изменялось. С первым понятно, а вот откуда взялось остальное, и что с ним делать? Значения статусов посмотрел, но как они себя поведут при создании ветки, непонятно. Как удачно отколоться от этой ветки?

Comment: Юноша, если хотите ответ, не изобретайте собственный жаргон. "Как удачно отколоться от этой ветки?" - переведите на общепринятый русский язык, а не заставляйте гадать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> откуда взялось остальное

[Svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ru/1.4/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status) говорит что:

```
X       3rd_party           # каталог является частью внешней зависимости
```

Таким образом это каталог, содержимое которого хранится в другом репозитории, а тут содержится только ссылка на него.

> что с ним делать?

Зависит от того, какой результат вы хотите получить.

> как они себя поведут при создании ветки

Они себя будут вести точно так же как и в trunc'е, потому что у svn, строго говоря, нет веток.